# Recyclerview preventing touch events after notifyItemChanged in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

The `Recyclerview` has a `ViewHolder` that contains `TextView` typically. The text content is selectable and when long press the text opening a selection menu. The `notifyItemChanged` function is calling from outside of the `Adapter` for resize the `Textview` font. The text selection menu available before resizing but after that the items not selectable. Don't open text selection menu when long press. There are no any request disallowing to event but the issue occurs after the `notifyItemChanged`.

**Edit:**

The problem is the TextView xml that item view of the Recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

The problem is solving if the `android:layout_width` of `TextView` is `WRAP_CONTENT`, but it must be `MATCH_PARENT`, what does that have to do with anything?

Recyclerview:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.ReadBookActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Edit-2:**

All of my text content wrapping many spans and there is RelativeSizeSpan for font size. It's editing when changing font size. And notifying the item with `notifyItemChanged(i)`. The problem sametimes don't occuring with using `notifyDataSetChanged()` withoud using `Wrap_Content` in the item.

**Edit-3:** The problem stems from editing RelativeSizeSpan completely, because it's renewing with new size when the changing font size. Removed renewing and it's using Textview.setTextSize() now, no problem.

Comment: Please post a minimum reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

So, reading the documentation for [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/drawerlayout/widget/DrawerLayout) it explicitly states:

> To use a DrawerLayout, position your primary content view as the first
> child with width and height of match_parent and no <layout_gravity>.
> **Add drawers as child views after the main content view and set the
> layout_gravity appropriately. Drawers commonly use match_parent for
> height with a fixed width.**

So basically your `DrawerLayout` CANNOT only contain 1 view, it needs to have your main content first, then your `RecyclerView` or whatever, and the `RecyclerView` needs to have a fixed width or potentially `wrap_content`. Items inside the `RecyclerView` can now be whatever you want.

Here is an example:

***activity_main.xml:*** (NB notice RecyclerView is not the first item and it has a layout_width of `wrap_content`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

***app_bar_main.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/main_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:elevation="@dimen/elevation"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

***content_main.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I haven't actually tested this myself but it should work as I have the exact same setup except, I'm using a `NavigationView` instead of a `RecyclerView` simply because I have a set amount of items in my drawer.

Comment: (Aside: when rendering `inline code`, note that you can use single backticks, and there is no need for triple backticks, though triples will indeed work. Triples are only needed for block formatting. It is ideal to use singles where possible, since this makes material easier to write and easier to edit).